# Discrete Mathematics, Predicates and Negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

https://i.gyazo.com/0dba70db4045aeae0a7b654b41405ef5.png

Question: For each of the following sentences, say whether the sentence is a true statement, a false statement, or a predicate. Also give the negation of each sentence.

a) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} n^2 > n$

b) If $ x>0 $ then there is no such $y$ that $y^2 = x$

c) $\forall p \in \mathbb{P} \left[ \exists n\in \mathbb{N} p=4n+1 \implies \exists a,b \in \mathbb{N} p = a^2 + b^2 \right] \\ \left[ 
\mathbb{P}\text{ denotes the set of all prime numbers.}\right]$

I'm unsure about these three, here are my attempts. Please also explain the difference between a predicate and true/false. I assumed it is a predicate when it can be either true or false.

a) Predicate. Negation is ¬(∃n ∈ N n²>n) 
b) True. Negation is, "When x<0 there is y such that y^2=x
c) No clue :P

Your help is truly appreciated!

Comment: A *predicate* in logic is an expression that denotes a *relation* between objects; when we assign to the language an interpretation $\mathcal I$, the expression $P(t,s)$ will be evaluated to **true** or **false** according to the fact that the the objects in the *domain* of the interpretation denoted by $t$ and $s$ (call them $t^{\mathcal I}$ and $s^{\mathcal I}$, respectively) have the relation denoted by $P$ (call it $P^{\mathcal I}$). In symbols : $(t^{\mathcal I}, s^{\mathcal I}) \in P^{\mathcal I}$.

Comment: A *closed* formula (i.e. a *sentence*) has a definite truth value in every interpretation: eithrt **true** or **false**. A formula with one *free* variable, like $(∃n ∈ \mathbb N \ n² > x)$ "works" like a unary *predicate*, i.e. denotes a "property" of objects of the domain of the interpretation (in this case: numbers); a formula with two free variables, like : $x \le y+2$ "works" like a binary *predicate*, i.e. denotes a binary relation, and so on.

Comment: a) Wrong; $∀n \ (n^2>n)$ has no free vars; thus, it is a *sentence*.

Comment: Its negation is : $\lnot ∀n \ (n^2>n)$ i.e. $∃n \ (n^2 \le n)$.

Comment: b) Wrong; $x>0 \to \lnot ∃y \ (y^2=x)$ has $x$ free; thus, it is a *predicate*.